# AzureFileCopy can't access the Blob Storage

Tags: azure-devops, copy

I am using YAML file to utilize AzureFIleCopy@4 to move artifact into the blob storage.
I gave roles as Storage Account Contributor and Storage Blob Data Contributor to the Service Connection that pipeline is using. When it is running, the pipeline can't identify the container name from the Storage Account, and when it is trying to create new one then error occured.

```
- task: AzureFileCopy@4
            inputs:
              SourcePath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/files'
              azureSubscription: $(service_connection)
              Destination: 'AzureBlob'
              storage: ${storageAccount}
              ContainerName: ${containerName}
              CleanTargetBeforeCopy: false

##[debug][Azure Call]Getting container: [Containername] in storage account: [StorageAccount]
##[debug]Container: partner-test does not exist in storage account: [StorageAccount]
##[debug]Creating container if the containerName provided does not exist
##[debug][Azure Call]Creating container: [Containername] in storage account: [StorageAccount]
##[debug]Azure.RequestFailedException: This request is not authorized to perform this operation.
```

I have tried to give different roles and different service connector, but it is not working at all. Do you have any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Hi there, Have you got a chance to check my answer below? May I know if it can resolve your issue? Thx.

Comment: @AlvinZhao I still have the same issue so far. We gave all roles required, but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think this "AzureFileCopy@4" task only helps "copy" a file from a destination to a storage account container, it will not help to create a storage account container.

so "existing storage account container should be pre-prepared."

Comment: I created the storage account prior to run the job, but it can't still identify the container.

Comment: try to add the additional azrue RBAC role "Storage Blob Data Contributor" to your service principal or user which used in "service connection"

Answer (score 0):

You may test with `AzureFileCopy@3`, which only requires the referenced service principal (app registration) by the ARM service connection to be the storage account `contributor` (no job function role required).

```
steps:
- task: AzureFileCopy@3
  displayName: 'AzureBlob File Copy'
  inputs:
    SourcePath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/files'
    azureSubscription: ARMSvcCnnAutoSub7
    Destination: AzureBlob
    storage: $(storageAccount)
    ContainerName: container1
```

You may also test with `AzureFileCopy@5` and grant the service principal `Storage Blob Data Owner` role.

Besides, please double check the Id of the application to which the storage account roles were assigned. Kindly note that different service principals can share the **same** display name.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, this is still not working fine. The process can identify the storage account, but after that, it can't parse the container. I gave the right role, but it is still not working fine.