# AzureFileCopy can't identify existing container

Tags: azure-devops, blob, filecopy

I am using AzureFileCopy@5 to move the artifact into the container in storage account. When it is running the process is trying to create the container which is already existed in the storage account. I gave the role to the SP as the storage account owner, but still not working fine. Can you help me with this?

```
##[debug][Azure Call]Getting container: adls-test in storage account: sa
##[debug]Container: adls-test does not exist in storage account: sa
##[debug]Creating container if the containerName provided does not exist
```

Comment: First answer on this question may have the answer you need, it mentions a different role: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77623289/azurefilecopy-cant-access-the-blob-storage